# How to Modify Attribute Value in XML using Xpath Java including commented Section

Tags: java, xml, xpath, comments

My requirement is updating reloadable="true" to reloadable="false". The below code is doing perfectly but it is not updating the attribute which is in comment section.
I know that comment() function would do but really no luck till now, below is by code

```
NodeList contextRoots = XMLUtil.xPathNodeList("//*[contains(@reloadable, 'true')]", ServerXML.getDocumentElement());
            for(int id = 0; id < contextRoots.getLength(); id++) 
            {
                Node value = contextRoots.item(id).getAttributes().getNamedItem("reloadable");
                String val = value.getNodeValue();
                value.setNodeValue(val.replaceAll("true", "false"));
            }
            return ServerXML;
```

Below is the XML

```
    <Context docBase="/UserManager" path="" reloadable="true"/>
    <Context docBase="/UserManager" path="" reloadable="true"/>

    <Context docBase="/AdminConsole" path="" reloadable="true"/>
    <Context docBase="/AdminConsole" path="" reloadable="true"/>

    <Context docBase="/public#cert" path="" reloadable="true"/>
    <Context docBase="/public#cert" path="" reloadable="true"/>

    <!-- Remove below comment block if CQI is installed--> 
    <!-- <Context docBase="CQI" path="" reloadable="true" />
    <Context docBase="CQI" path="" reloadable="true" /> -->
```

Comment: Please provide short snippet of xml that you are working on and what attribute you want to replace.

Comment: @svasa I have Updated. Thank You

Comment: Did the answer below work ? Thanks.

Comment: Along with Context there are several other tags, a code should modify if reloadable="true" is present in other tags as well. Thank You

Comment: Then you have condition `data.trim().contains("reloadable=\"true\"")` instead of `data.trim().startsWith("<Context")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could detect if node is a [`COMMENT_NODE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#COMMENT_NODE) and see if it's data starts with `<Context` and replace `reloadable=true` with `reloadable=false` as in below code:

```
 InputSource inputSource = new InputSource( new FileInputStream( new File("commentupdate.xml")  ) );

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse( inputSource );
NodeList nodeList = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
{
    if ( nodeList.item(i).getNodeType() == Element.COMMENT_NODE ) 
    {
        Comment comment=(Comment) nodeList.item(i);
        String data = comment.getData();
        if ( data.trim().startsWith( "<Context") )
        {
            data = data.replaceAll("reloadable\\s*=\\s*\"true\"", "reloadable=\"false\"");
            Comment newComment = doc.createComment(data);
            comment.getParentNode().appendChild(newComment);
            comment.getParentNode().removeChild(comment);
        }

    }
}

TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml" );
transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "true" );
transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
StreamResult sr = new StreamResult( new File( "commentupdate.xml" ) );            
transformer.transform( new DOMSource(doc), sr );
```